# Телеграмм бот с функцией поисковика на aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Столкнулся с такой проблемой когда делал бота на python. Недавно перешёл на aiogram с telebot. В telebot я пользовался функцией bot.register_next_step_handler(),чтобы просить ввод у пользователя. В aiogram такой функции нет, мне посоветовали использовать fsm. Чтобы разобраться что такое фсм и с чем его едят я обошёл весь интернет и Ютуб, но кроме примеров с функцией регистрации я там ничего не нашел. Помогите советом пожалуйста.

Comment: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py

Comment: Прям вееесь интернет обошли? [вот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_pPNlXMzsw)

Comment: Google, Яндекс, DuckDuck Go